# Background Audio mode with MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm working on an iOS app that uses `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer` to play songs from Apple Music to the user.

My app should be able to append songs to the Music player's queue based on messages it receives from a server. I have this working with a simple WebSocket connection between the app and the server, but **as soon as the app enters the background the socket is automatically closed** (which makes sense).

**Because the actual music playback is done by the Music app, I can't use the  `Background Audio` background mode to keep my app alive.** Is there a way around this?

Things I have already considered (and why I don't think they will work):

- **Remote Notifications** are throttled too slow to be of any real use
- **Background App Refresh** is also too slow
- **PushKit / VoIP** (the app isn't a VoIP app)
- **Playing "blank" or nearly silent audio over the actual audio** which seems too "hacky" and likely won't pass app review
- **Using background location tracking** (again, almost certainly won't pass review)
- **Ditching `systemMusicPlayer` completely and using `AVAudioPlayer` with the Apple Music API** (this would be reinventing the wheel a little bit and would force streaming even if the media was downloaded)
- **Using `applicationQueuePlayer` and just forcing the user to stay in app** (this would be a bad user experience imo, they should be able to listen in the background)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 15 and later, you should be able to just set the background plist flag for your app, and then just use ApplicationMusicPlayer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickit/applicationmusicplayer